# TypeScript : Opting-out of noUncheckedIndexedAccess on a per-case basis

Tags: typescript

My TS code use the compiler option [noUncheckedIndexedAccess](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess) which adds `undefined` as a possible value to all index signatures.

```js
type Type = {[k: string]: string}
const obj: Type = {}
obj.hello // TS detects type `string | undefined`
```

Fine ... Now, I am defining a `Proxy` which returns a default value for each property, e.g. :

```js
type Type = {[k: string]: string}

const obj: Type = {}

const p = new Proxy<Type>(obj, {
    get: (_, k) => {
        return '_' + String(k)
    },
})

p.hello // TS detects type `string | undefined`
```

I would like any member of the proxied object `p` to be typed as `string` instead of `string | undefined` (without deactivating `noUncheckedIndexedAccess`). Is this possible ? Something like :

```
type Type = {[k: string]: NonNullable<string>}
```

Comment: Hm, [this fiddle](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oG8DaBrAXFAzsATgJYB2A5gLrZ5FkC+AUPQMYD2xeULARgFbZyQoSZA2ZsOYIVGIQA7lAAK+FgA8QAHgEQAfAApuPADQp6UM1FIRg2XQH1j6AJRDtJ8+6j4rAV3zEoAOS2AVAA1FAAygQkpLpOpua0hvS0joxgAHQAFhAANrksGbkQZMBZ9EA) detects `p.hello` as a `string`. Didn't change any of the settings ...

Comment: Same with me, tried using several ts playgrounds.

Comment: This is the behavior of https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#noUncheckedIndexedAccess which defaults to off, partly because of difficulties like this one.

Comment: Oh yeah ... sorry forgot to mention that I use that compiler option ;) thankns @AlexWayne I'll edit the question ...

Comment: This is a missing feature as per [ms/TS#47594](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47594). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yes that's exactly the case.

Comment: I'll write an answer when I get the chance.

Comment: Well, that's exactly the point of that option, so if you don't want that behaviour, don't use that option.

Comment: @derpirscher Mostly, that'd be fine. But in this case the proxy guarantees that `undefined` can never happen. But with this global option enabled, the type cannot express that certainty. That kind of sucks.

Comment: @AlexWayne Yeah, it kindof does. But there seems no way around that currently ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript's [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures) types were never intended to represent an object for which every possible key has a defined property value. Indeed, such a type really only makes sense for a subset of [`Proxy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) objects, and that use case isn't very common (compared to dictionary/record/array types, which is what index signatures were intended to model).

Still, when [the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler option](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess) is disabled, you can sort of treat an index signature as if it were such an all-properties-exist `Proxy`, since the possibility of `undefined` is ignored.  If you still want that behavior when you *enable* that option, well, you're out of luck, at least for now.  Such a feature is not part of the language.

Now, there is an open feature request for this at [microsoft/TypeScript#47594](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47594) to support your use case. It wouldn't hurt for you to go there and give it a .  Of course, it probably wouldn't really *help*, either.  Currently there are only a few dozen upvotes on it, so it's not anywhere near the top of the list for community-requested features.  It's also listed as "Awaiting More Feedback", meaning that before they would even consider implementing it, they'd want to hear more about why the feature would be needed and why existing approaches don't work well enough. So you might want to add your use case as a comment, at least if it is different from or more compelling than those already listed.  But again, I doubt it would have much of an effect.